# Batch to import browser homepages for Windows XP-10

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd

I use a batch file to import data from all the Windows computers that I work on. System Info and other relevant information. I'm trying to add to it the browser homepages because people don't like to lose there homepage and I don't like opening every browser just to find this information. I can do it on IE but Google Chrome and Firefox use JavaScript and that is where I get lost.

This is what for IE

```
@echo off
setLocal
cd /d %~dp0
set Start`Page=
REM Get IE Home Page
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page"') do set Start`Page=%%~b
echo IE Home Page: %Start`Page% >> Homepages.txt
%~dp0Homepages.txt %MAC%
pause
```

Comment: @Mofi Maybe you should read it again. I'm not asking to change anything. Only to find this information. I can find many Google searches on how to change the homepage. I want this information so if I reset a browser I can put the homepage back like it was before Or if I install an AV that hijacks the browser I can change it back. I fix computers for customers and I understand your pain. Try to understand mine.

Comment: Chrome protects its preferences by storing a duplicate `Secure Preferences` file with CRC-like hashsums inside the data folder so to change something you will have to backup and restore the entire file. Instead try using [Chrome policies](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en).

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't want to change anything. I don't think I will find any answers in Chrome policies. Thanks. To bad I can't have the batch file open Chrome. Copy the URL and Close Chrome....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- #### Chrome

  Extract from all Chrome "persons":

  ```
  @echo off
  set js="%temp%\extractChromeHomepage%random%.js"

  rem List all Chrome persons
  (
      set /p .=settings=<nul
      type "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"
      echo ;for^(var k in settings.profile.info_cache^) WScript.echo^(k^);
  )>%js%

  rem Get the homepage for each Chrome person
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %js%') do (
      (
          set /p .=settings=<nul
          type "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\%%a\Secure Preferences"
          echo ;WScript.echo^("Chrome homepage (%%a): " + settings.homepage^);
      )>%js%
      cscript //nologo %js%
  )
  del %js%
  ```

  The output:

  > Chrome homepage (Default): https://www.google.com/
  >   Chrome homepage (Profile 4): undefined

  - If the homepage is not set it prints `undefined`, this can be customized if you like
  - To redirect the output to a file add `>>somefile.txt` on the last `cscript` line
- #### Firefox

  Extract from all profiles:

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%a in ('
      findstr /i "Name= Path=" "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini"
  ') do (
      if %%a==Name (
          set "name=%%b"
      ) else (
          set "profile=%%b"
          set "profile=%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\!profile:/=\!\prefs.js"
          if exist "!profile!" (
              for /f "tokens=2 delims=,) " %%b in ('
                  findstr "\<browser.startup.homepage\>" "!profile!"
              ') do echo Firefox homepage ^(!name!^): %%~b
          )
      )
  )
  endlocal
  ```

  The output:

  > Firefox homepage (default): about:newtab
  >   Firefox homepage (nightly): about:newtab

Comment: Yes, that perfect for Google Chrome! Thank you

Comment: @BobbyBrown, added FF.

Comment: I'll test on multiple machines as soon as I get a chance. Edge looks like a lost cause but it's okay not to many people know how to change it yet anyways. So it hasn't been a problem. Thanks for answer!

Comment: I have now ran this on over 100 computers. It dont work 100% of the time but it does work on everything from XP to Windows 10. I love it and it saves me a lot of time. Thanks